# Sort several bar charts and tables simultaneously in PowerBI

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-custom-visuals

I am new to PowerBI and was hopping that someone could help me out.

I have several bar charts as well as tables with multiple variables for which all of them share one common column. The issue I am facing is that I want to sort the bar charts or tables based on a specific column and want the order for the rest to be updated simultaneously. Do you have any idea how I can achieve this?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I suspect that isn't currently possible.

Comment: Thank you for your response @AlexisOlson! Isnt it possible for them (i.e. table and bar charts) to share the same column?

Comment: You can certainly have multiple visuals using the same column, but sorting one visual doesn't affect other visuals as far as I'm aware.

Comment: @AlexisOlson, thank you once again :) Do you know how I can create several visuals that share the same column?